Interrupt generation in EC200U-CNAC module
can I create External interrupt (RX) when I send SMS from any phone to EC200u module
I am trying to send SMS to ec200u module by phone when I send SMS and after received it should generate interrupt on RX then it will perform there operation using code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
